# Method invocation failed because [System.IO.DirectoryInfo] does not contain a method named 'replace'

Tags: powershell

I have a few hundred folders to represent all my subnets.

Example, for the folder name

> 172.31.3.250_29

represents the subnet

> 172.31.3.250/29

Because you can't have "/" in windows folder names.

I have about 250 of these folders.

I am writing a powershell script that will take each folder name and run a script against the "subnet" that the folder represents, and dump a log in that folder.

However, I'm stuck on a simple issue.

I have successfully been able to extract the name of all sub folders in a folder

I need to replace the "_" with "/" to denote proper subnet format for my script.

```
$NmapFolder = Get-ChildItem -Path "U:\nmap reports\Nmap Subnet Scans\August2019" -Recurse -Directory -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$data = ForEach ($items in $NmapFolder){
    $items = $items.replace('_','/')
    #eventually will have nmap script logic
    #eventually will have "wait for nmap done" check before proceeding with next folder/subnet
    write-host $items
}
```

Which produces the error...

```
Method invocation failed because [System.IO.DirectoryInfo] does not contain a method named 'replace'.
At line:6 char:1
+ $items = $items.replace('_','/')
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

Comment: 1) I would recommend renaming `$items` to `$item` since you access only one item at a time in the `foreach` loop. 2) The code would be `$items.Name.Replace('_','/')`. Replace is a method for `String`, not `DirectoryInfo` (and the `Name` property is `String`).

Comment: Hm. I will eventually be running $items (or, $item as it soon shall be called) as a string, so it sounds like I need to convert the variable to a string. I need to figure out how to do that.  @Bill_Stewart

Comment: @Bill_Stewart, actually nevermind, your suggestion worked perfectly. Thank you and may your day be fantastic!

Answer (score 2):

`Get-ChildItem` returns a `System.IO.DirectoryInfo` or `System.IO.FileInfo` object, not a string. Since you specified `-Directory`, you will first need to convert the `DirectoryInfo` objects to strings

One easy way to do this would be to change the first line of your code:

```
$NmapFolder = @( ( Get-ChildItem -Path "U:\nmap reports\Nmap Subnet Scans\August2019" -Recurse -Directory -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue ).Name )
```

This will roll up the Name property of every returned `DirectoryInfo` object into an array of strings, which you can then iterate over. However, if you have a deeper directory structure to traverse (I assume you might since you are using `-Recurse`), you may want to consider making use of piping your `Get-ChildItem` command into `Resolve-Path -Relative`, and parsing your subnet folder name from that array of strings, as it looks like eventually you may try writing something back into that folder from this script.